# GoogleMaps V2 android get marker icon

Tags: android, bitmap, google-maps-android-api-2, marker

I'm currently implementing GoogleMapsV2 and try to port the old functionality I had in MapsV1. in V1, I was able to subclass an `OverlayItem` and save the icon i put inside. Now I have to create a `MarkerOption` based on a model object, add it to the `GoogleMap` to get a Marker back.

Because the Marker class is final, and GoogleMaps isn't providing a Method to get a handle on it (like a `SQLiteCursorFactory`), I feel unable to get the icon back I put inside.

If i keep the `MarkerOptions` object, I could get back a `BitmapDescriptor` which has only one (obfuscated) method `aW()` which is returning a `b` object.

I'm quite shure that the Bitmap must be somewhere inside this object because its drawn on the `GoogleMap`. What is the best way to get it back from the marker.

I'm currently mapping the Marker to my model upon creation inside a `HashMap<Marker, ModelObj>` but from there I have to re-create the icon everytime I want to access it. This feels simply wrong, and I'm wondering if there is a better method of accessing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm quite shure that the Bitmap must be somewhere inside this object because its drawn on the GoogleMap.

That's far from certain. The map is rendered by another process. So, while the `Bitmap` is in *that* process, it may not be in yours.

> What is the best way to get it back from the marker.

You don't. That's a write-only API.

> I'm currently mapping the Marker to my model upon creation inside a HashMap but from there I have to re-create the icon everytime I want to access it.

Then cache it yourself. Nowadays, `Marker` has `getId()`, which is probably better than using `Marker` itself as the key. But then either tuck your icon into `ModelObj` or have a separate bitmap cache. You will have to determine for yourself if the CPU vs. RAM trade-off warrants caching or regenerating the icon.

Comment: never noticed marker.getId(). Thanks for that hint. If there is no other solution I've missed, then I will cache them myself.

Comment: @RafaelT: "never noticed marker.getId()" -- yeah, I am uncertain when they added it, as I had missed it for a while too.

Comment: can you also confirm that the api about Marker icon which says "... You can't change the icon once you've created the marker." is simply wrong, as there is a `setIcon(BitmapDescriptor)` method that WILL WORK? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker#setIcon%28com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor%29

Comment: @RafaelT: `setIcon()` was a relatively recent addition to the Maps V2 API. If there are portions of the documentation that claim marker icons cannot be changed, file issues to have those docs fixed.

Comment: I'll do that, but it seems to me they do not really care about, as I have no response for issues I already filed. But thats another story. Thanks for the insights